# How to get a 1024 x 600 Android emulator working?

Tags: android, emulation

I'm trying to emulate an Acer AOD250 that has a 1024x600 screen and comes with Android.  If I create an AVD with default settings except for resolution of 1024x600 and SDK 3, the emulator does not start.  The largest I can get working is 670x600.  At larger resolutions, sometimes the emulator starts, but does not complete the boot.  Is there a memory setting or something that I can change to allow the emulator to work on a screen this big?

Answer (score 3):

Samsung release a plug-in for galaxy TAB !
screen resolution of 1024x600
http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/galaxyTab.do

Answer (score 1):

You can run Android in a virtual machine (e.g.: [Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/)) using a [Android iso](http://code.google.com/p/live-android/)